# AutoIt unzipping files

Tags: zip, unzip, autoit, solution

I've been searching all day for a solution to `unzip` a file with `AutoIt Script`. I would like to unzip a file called `full.zip` to a `folder`.

This is my last place to turn since I can't find a solution of my own. I have found many solutions made by others; `AutoIt3` files containing functions, but the code has issues of which I do not understand, and I'm unable to them copy here because I'm using a screen reader and it doesn't seem to format properly. This is why I can not copy code here.

Does anyone know of a method, tutorial or resource that I can use to **unzip a file with AutoIt?**

Thanks for any help,
josh.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of solutions people have coded. A few examples are the [7zip UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/85094-7zip/), [Zip.au3](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/73425-zipau3-udf-in-pure-autoit/), [zipfldr UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/116565-zip-udf-zipfldrdll-library/). If those are not working for you it is most likely because of small changes to AutoIt, which is usually just `#incude`s being restructured.

I usually just keep 7za.exe (7-zip's standalone executable, 7-zip can be downloaded from [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), and then after installing you can copy the `7za.exe` from its program directory).

Then it becomes as simple as a call to `RunWait` to create the archive:

```
RunWait("7za.exe a MyNewArchive.zip file1.ext file2.ext ...")
```

And then to unzip:

```
RunWait('7za.exe x MyArchive.zip -o"Path\To\MyOutputFolder"')
```

The 7-zip [FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html) also mentions that you can use this exe in your own applications (including commercial ones) provided you mention it in the documentation and provide a link. That means you are ok to use `FileInstall(...)` to include `7za.exe` in the compiled `.exe`.