# Unattended install of AutoIt 3.3.6.1: need 32-bit version but can only get 64-bit version

Tags: ruby, windows, 32bit-64bit, nsis, autoit

I want to do an automatic/unattended installation of [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), then be able to drive AutoItX from a Ruby script.

When I'm done, I should be able to run this rudimentary code and have it succeed:

```
require 'win32ole'
WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
```

Since it appears to be a Nullsoft (NSIS) installer, I can force a quiet installation with the `/S` flag.  But after I install it and try the code above, it generates this error:

```
WIN32OLERuntimeError: failed to create WIN32OLE object from `AutoItX3.Control'
    HRESULT error code:0x80040154
      Class not registered
```

It seems as if AutoIt's installer defaults to installing the 64-bit version since I'm using the 64-bit version of Windows 7.  But I can't get AutoIt to work with Ruby unless I install AutoIt's 32-bit version (I believe this is because Ruby for Windows is still 32-bit).

Does anyone know of a way to force the 32-bit version in an unattended installation?

Comment: Can you not just get distribute a copy of AutoItX and register the dll manually?

Comment: @Matt, your hint to "register the dll manually" was the missing piece of my puzzle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the AutoIt installer *does* install the necessary 32-bit DLL along with the 64-bit library, but apparently it doesn't register it properly.

By `cd`-ing to the `AutoItX` subdirectory of the installation root and running this command:

```
regsvr32 AutoItX3.dll
```

...I was able to make it work with Ruby's WIN32OLE library.

Comment: You probably want to use the `/s` switch to silently register it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [ZIP](http://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?autoit3/autoit-v3.zip) Version of AutoIt. You can then just use the `AutoIt.exe` instead of the `AutoIt_x64.exe`.

If you need to, you can pack it with an unzip utility like `7za.exe` as mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249003/959484).